# What is going on in this javascript, and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension, with a javascript file that gets executed. The javascript file makes this call to background.html:

**action.js**

```
var action = "";
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getLocalStorage", key: "action"},
  function(response) {
     alert(response.data);
     action = response.data;
 });
alert('action:'+action);
```

and in **background.html:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.method == "getLocalStorage")
  sendResponse({data: localStorage[request.key]});
else
  sendResponse({});
```

The behavior that i get is an alert box saying "`action:`" and then an alert box saying "`video`" which is the correct value for action.

Why are these alert boxes showing out of order, and why isn't the variable `action` getting the `response.data` value? Does it have to do with a delay from the `sendRequest` method? How can I make the script wait, so that I can get the value? (I'm going to need to do this request multiple times - I have 4 values that I need to request)

Comment: *"How can I make the script wait..."* You don't *want* it to wait. What you need is to accommodate your code to work with the asynchronous execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `sendRequest` is an asynchronous method (much like an Ajax call). The script does not halt and wait for the response.

The only solution is to call the other functions which need the response *inside* the callback.

Comment: I need to make this call 4 times, to get 4 values, and it doesn't seem to work to return the localStorage in bulk. If i put everything inside the callback, I can't make this call 4 times.

Comment: I don't see a problem to create a function which issues the request and call it four times. Or to create a queue. Do you want to execute these four calls one after another or can the run at the same time?

Comment: I want to call the function 4 times, and I need all 4 values to be returned before the rest of the code proceeds. For example: in my code from action.js above, I need the request to complete before the `alert('action:'+action);`, and I need it to do it 4 times.

Comment: @roviuser: Then use a counter (shared variable), increase the counter in each callback and  call a method which checks how many calls have been finished. Only if the counter equals `4`, call another method (which is basically the rest of your code) and pass the values. If you search on SO for something like *wait for multiple Ajax calls*, you will find different solutions for that. As said, everything which has to operate on the response value, has to be in or called from the callbacks.